# How to pass value a public variable to another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, spawn, ienumerator

I am trying to pass a variable from my Game Manager script to my Player Controller script. Using the following code I get the error message "playerIsAlive does not exist in the current context".

Game Manager Script:

```cs
playerControllerScript = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerController>();
    
void Update()
{
    if(playerIsAlive == false)
    {
        StartCoroutine(PlayerRespawn);
    }
}
```

Player Controller Script:

```cs
public bool playerIsAlive;

else if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
{
    playerIsAlive = false;
    Destroy(gameObject);                    
}
```

Comment: `playerControllerScript.playerIsAlive` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of referencing the boolean as `playerIsAlive` you should do `playerControllerScript.playerIsAlive` in Game Manager script.

Answer (score 0):

To access a field (or method) from another object, you must follow this syntax: *[objectReferenceVariable]* **.** *[field name]*. Notice the dot.

In your case, accessing this variable would like this: `playerControllerScript.playerIsAlive`.

---

There is missing elements in your description though, so this answer may not fit your problem. I am deducting some informations.
Also, in the second part (about the PlayerController), their is an `else` that have nothing to do here.

*I do not have enouth StackOverflow reputation yet* to comment on your question first but beware of the code format in your question.

Display all necessary information, and it is better to give each code file its own chunk of code.

For example:

```cs
public class GameManager
{
    private PlayerController playerControllerScript;

    void Start()
    {
        playerControllerScript = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerController>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(playerIsAlive == false)
        {
          StartCoroutine(PlayerRespawn);
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
public class PlayerController
{
    public bool playerIsAlive;
}
```

---

It’s also seem that you have little experience with Unity (maybe with C# too).
Don’t hesitate to check online tutorial. Here is few links:

- [Unity](https://learn.unity.com)
- [C#](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/csharp)